zenoh bridge not detected
I'm trying to pub simple message on one laptop and subscribe the message on the other laptop.
Both laptops are macpro connected to the same WIFI.
Laptop1:
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0
zenoh-bridge-ros2dds

returns Zenoh can be reached at: tcp/192.168.64.2:7447
On new terminal:
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=0
ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker

Laptop2:
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
zenoh-bridge-ros2dds -e tcp/192.168.64.2:7447

also returns Zenoh can be reached at: tcp/192.168.64.2:7447
On new terminal,
export ROS_DOMAIN_ID=1
ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener

Does anyone know why there is no zenoh bridge detected?
If I run both of these on same laptop with exception of running
zenoh-bridge-ros2dds --connect tcp/0.0.0.0:7447 --listen tcp/127.0.0.1:7448
instead of
zenoh-bridge-ros2dds -e tcp/192.168.64.2:7447 this returns error
Unable to open listener tcp/[::]:7447: Can not create a new TCP listener bound to tcp/[::]:7447: [[::]:7447: Address already in use (os error 98) at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/zenoh-link-tcp-1.0.0-beta.3/src/unicast.rs:294.] at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/zenoh-link-tcp-1.0.0-beta.3/src/unicast.rs:379. Failed to start Zenoh runtime: Can not create a new TCP listener bound to tcp/[::]:7447: [[::]:7447: Address already in use (os error 98) at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/zenoh-link-tcp-1.0.0-beta.3/src/unicast.rs:294.] at /cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/zenoh-link-tcp-1.0.0-beta.3/src/unicast.rs:379.. Exiting...

I don't have issue pub/sub talker and listener.
I also tried not running export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp, but no use..

Running zenoh-bridge-ros2dds in this scenario works well on my side (Both are Ubuntu).
Could you please provide the version (Both bridge and ROS 2) you're using?
Now I'm using the latest version built from source code running with ROS 2 Jazzy.
Besides, could you also check the connection availability between the two hosts?
There might be some firewall issues blocking the connection.
Using Zenoh simple examples is another good way to check.
